# How do I resolve this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python, linux, dependencies, python-poetry

So I set up this project with `poetry` plus virtual environments like 4 days ago and it was working well but coming back today it is throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/akin/software_eng/yor_scraper/yor_scraper/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from yor_scraper.global_voices_scraper import scrape_global_voices
  File "/home/akin/software_eng/yor_scraper/yor_scraper/global_voices_scraper.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

see my .toml file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "yor-scraper"
version = "0.1.0"
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "yor_scraper"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
beautifulsoup4 = "^4.12.2"
lxml = "^4.9.3"
requests = "^2.31.0"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

And I'm trying to use it these files:

`__main__.py`:

```py
from yor_scraper.global_voices_scraper import scrape_global_voices

def main():
    scrape_global_voices()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is my `global_voices_scraper.py` file:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # this line fails
from pathlib import Path

import requests as HTTP # and also this line

def scrape_global_voices():
    print('Fetching...')
    # other codes go here...
```

how can I resolve this error?

Comment: It sounds like it's not using the poetry env when you run the script. You need to either use `poetry run python <script name>` or first activate the poetry env with `poetry shell` and then run the script. See https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#using-poetry-run

Comment: Thanks @Anentropic! I will look into it. I also tried deleting the .lock file and then ran poetry install and it worked. However, I fear this issue might happen again.

Comment: activate your `env` while running this script otherwise it will use python of base env which will not have these `modules`.